# How to aggregate string length sequence base on an indicator sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with two keys and their values are lists of strings.

I want to calculate string length of one list base on an indicator in another list.

It's difficult to frame the question is words, so let's look at an example.

Here is an example dictionary:

```
thisdict ={
  'brand': ['Ford','bmw','toyota','benz','audi','subaru','ferrari','volvo','saab'],
  'type': ['O','B','O','B','I','I','O','B','B']
}
```

Now, I want to add an item to the dictionary that corresponds to string cumulative-length of "brand-string-sequence" base on condition of "type-sequence".

Here is the criteria:

If type = 'O', set string length = 0 for that index.

If type = 'B', set string length to the corresponding string length.

If type = 'I', it's when things get complicated. You would want to look back the sequence and sum up string length until you reach to the first 'B'.

Here is an example output:

```
thisdict ={
  "brand": ['Ford','bmw','toyota','benz','audi','subaru','ferrari','volvo','saab'],
  'type': ['O','B','O','B','I','I','O','B','B'],
  'cumulative-length':[0,3,0,4,8,14,0,5,4]  
}
```

where 8=len(benz)+len(audi) and 14=len(benz)+len(audi)+len(subaru)

Note that in the real data I'm working on, the sequence can be one "B" and followed by an arbitrary number of "I"s. ie. ['B','I','I','I','I','I','I',...,'O'] so I'm looking for a solution that is robust in such situation.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the zip fucntion to tie the brand and type together. Then just keep a running total as you loop through the dictionary values. This solution will support any length series and any length string in the brand list. I am assuming that `len(thisdict['brand']) == len(thisdict['type'])`.

```
thisdict = {
  'brand': ['Ford','bmw','toyota','benz','audi','subaru','ferrari','volvo','saab'],
  'type': ['O','B','O','B','I','I','O','B','B']
}

lengths = []
running_total = 0
for b, t in zip(thisdict['brand'], thisdict['type']):

    if t == 'O':
        lengths.append(0)

    elif t == 'B':
        running_total = len(b)
        lengths.append(running_total)

    elif t == 'I':
        running_total += len(b)
        lengths.append(running_total)

print(lengths)
# [0, 3, 0, 4, 8, 14, 0, 5, 4]
```

Generating random data

```
import random
import string

def get_random_brand_and_type():

    n = random.randint(1,8)
    b = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(n))
    t = random.choice(['B', 'I', 'O'])

    return b, t

thisdict = {
    'brand': [],
    'type': []
}

for i in range(random.randint(1,20)):
    b, t = get_random_brand_and_type()
    thisdict['brand'].append(b)
    thisdict['type'].append(t)
```

yields the following result:

```
{'type': ['B', 'B', 'O', 'I', 'B', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'O'], 
 'brand': ['O', 'BSYMLFN', 'OF', 'SO', 'KPQGRW', 'DLCWW', 'VLU', 'ZQE', 'GEUHERHE']}
[1, 7, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0]
```